# Loading .txt file as a dict, but exclude commented rows

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some data in a txt file and I would like to load it into a list of dicts.  I would normally use `csv.ReadDict(open('file'))`, however this data does not have the key values in the first row.  Instead it has a number of rows commented out before the data actually begins.  Also, sometimes, the commented rows will not always be at beginning of the file, but could be at the end of the file.

However, all line should always have the same fields, and I guess I could hard-code these field names (or key values) as they shouldn't change.

**Sample Date**

```
# twitter data
# retrieved at: 07.08.2014
# total number of records: 5
# exported by: userXYZ
# fields: date, time, username, source
10.12.2013; 02:00; tweeterA; web
10.12.2013; 02:01; tweeterB; iPhone
10.13.2013; 02:04; tweeterC; android
10.13.2013; 02:08; tweeterC; web
10.13.2013; 02:10; tweeterD; iPhone
```

Below is the what I've been able to figure out so far, but I need some help getting it worked out.

**My Code**

```
header = ['date', 'time', 'username', 'source']
data = []

for line in open('data.txt'):
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        data.append(line)
```

**Desired Format**

```
[{'date':'10.12.2013', 'time':'02:00', 'username':'tweeterA', 'source':,'web'},
 {'date':'10.12.2013', 'time':'02:01', 'username':'tweeterB', 'source':,'iPhone'},
 {'date':'10.12.2013', 'time':'02:04', 'username':'tweeterC', 'source':,'android'},
 {'date':'10.12.2013', 'time':'02:08', 'username':'tweeterC', 'source':,'web'},
 {'date':'10.12.2013', 'time':'02:10', 'username':'tweeterD', 'source':,'iPhone'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a list of dicts where each dict corresponds to a row try this:

```
list_of_dicts = [{key: value for (key, value) in zip(header, line.strip().split('; '))} for line in open('abcd.txt') if not line.strip().startswith('#')]
```

Comment: You can just use `dict()` instead of the dictionary comprehension... this is more readable in my opinion: `dict(zip(header, line.strip().split('; ')))`

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in open('data.txt'):
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        data.append(line.split("; "))
```

at least assuming I understand you correctly

or more succinct

```
data = [line.split("; ") for line in open("data.txt") if not line.strip().startswith("#")]
list_of_dicts = map(lambda row:dict(zip(header,row)),data)
```

depending on your version of python you may get an iterator back from map in which case just do

```
 list_of_dicts = list(map(lambda row:dict(zip(header,row)),data))
```

Comment: You could split event with space in `"; "`

Comment: there ... now it splits the leading space as well

Comment: @JoranBeasley - that loads the data as a list of lists.  I would like to load the data as a list of dicts with the key values I defined.